# Geonear sort by distance and time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following data:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a8c1ba3996c909184d7a22"),
    "uid" : "1db82e8a-2038-4818-b805-76a46ba62639",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2015-07-17T08:50:02.892Z"),
    "palce" : "aa",
    "sex" : 1,
    "longdis" : 1,
    "location" : [ 106.607312, 29.575281 ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a8c1ba3996c909184d7a24"),
    "uid" : "1db82e8a-2038-4818-b805-76a46ba62639",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2015-07-17T08:50:02.920Z"),
    "palce" : "bbb",
    "sex" : 1,
    "longdis" : 1,
    "location" : [ 106.589896, 29.545098 ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a8c1ba3996c909184d7a25"),
    "uid" : "1db82e8a-2038-4818-b805-76a46ba62639",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2015-07-17T08:50:02.922Z"),
    "palce" : "ccc",
    "sex" : 1,
    "longdis" : 1,
    "location" : [ 106.590758, 29.566713 ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a8c1ba3996c909184d7a26"),
    "uid" : "1db82e8a-2038-4818-b805-76a46ba62639",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2015-07-17T08:50:02.923Z"),
    "palce" : "ddd",
    "sex" : 1, 
    "longdis" : 1, 
    "location" : [ 106.637039, 29.561436 ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a8c1bc3996c909184d7a27"),
    "uid" : "1db82e8a-2038-4818-b805-76a46ba62639",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2015-07-17T08:50:04.499Z"),
    "palce" : "eee",
    "sex" : 1,
    "longdis" : 1,
    "location" : [ 106.539522, 29.57929 ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a8d12e78292fa3837ebae4"),
    "uid" : "1db82e8a-2038-4818-b805-76a46ba62639",
    "createdate" : ISODate("2015-07-17T09:55:58.947Z"),
    "palce" : "fff",
    "sex" : 1,
    "longdis" : 1,
    "location" : [ 106.637039, 29.561436 ]
}
```

I want to first of all, sort by the distance, if the distance is the same, sort by the time.

my command :

```js
db.runCommand( { 
   geoNear: "paging", 
   near: [106.606033,29.575897 ],
   spherical : true,
   maxDistance : 1/6371,
   minDistance:0/6371,
   distanceMultiplier: 6371,
   num:2,
   query: {'_id': {'$nin': []}} 
})
```

or

```js
db.paging.find({
   'location':{
       $nearSphere: [106.606033,29.575897],
       $maxDistance:1
   }
}).limit(5).skip((2 - 1) * 2).sort({createdate:-1})
```

How can I sort on both "nearest" and "createddate"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct query to use here uses the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) which has the [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) pipeline stage to assist with this. It's also the only place you get to "sort" by multiple keys, as unforntunately the "geospatial" `$nearSphere` does not have a "meta" projection for "distance" like `$text` has a "score".

Also the `geoNear` database command you are using can also not be used with "cursor" `.sort()` in that way either.

```js
db.paging.aggregate([
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": [106.606033,29.575897 ],
        "spherical": true,
        "distanceField": "distance",
        "distanceMuliplier": 6371,
        "maxDistance": 1/6371
    }},
    { "$sort": { "distance": 1, "createdate": -1 } },
    { "$skip": ( 2-1 ) * 2 },
    { "$limit": 5 }
])
```

That is the equivalent of what you are trying to do.

With the aggregation framework you use the ["pipeline operators"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) instead of "cursor modifiers" to do things like `$sort`, `$skip` and `$limit`. Also these **must** be in a Logical order, whereas the cursor modifiers generally work it out.

It's a "pipeline", just like "Unix pipe". `|`

Also, be careful with "maxDistance" and "distanceMuliplier". Since your co-ordinates are in "legacy co-ordinate pairs" and not `GeoJSON` format, then the distances are measured in "radians". If you have GeoJSON stored location data then the result is returned in "meters".

Comment: user follow command not work:   db.paging.aggregate([
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": [106.606033,29.575897 ],
        "spherical": true,
        "distanceField": "distance",
        "distanceMuliplier": 6371,
        "maxDistance": 1/6371
    }},
    { "$sort": { "distance": 1, "createdate": -1 },
    { "$skip": ( 2-1 ) * 2 },
    { "$limit": 5 }
])       if remove "{ "$sort": { "distance": 1, "createdate": -1 },"  its works ok.

Comment: @user2968187 Typing mistake by me. Missed a closing `}` on the `$sort` stage. Fixed now.

Comment: @user2968187 Go and play, and have fun with it. Like I said, aggregate is the only real way to go for multiple sorting criteria in this case. Don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) when you are done.

Comment: but use aggregate  performance bad ,  look this : http://emptysqua.re/blog/paging-geo-mongodb/

Comment: @user2968187 Don't believe the "hype". And you are reading the wrong part. Aggregate is not bad in itself it's the "skip" and "limit", just the same as with a normal `.skip()` and `.limit()` that is **bad** for performance. But that also "was not your question". If you have another question about "paging performance", then please post that question, as it requires a detailed answer in itself. The "performance" here is no different in any way from the examples you tried. With the only difference in that it actually works.